# TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function on React Hook Form using EmailJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, react-hook-form

I got an error once the form is submitted:
**TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function.**

Here is my code:

```
import {React} from 'react';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";

const NameForm = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', e.target, 'YOUR_USER_ID')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);

      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
      e.target.reset();
  }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-center text-md-left mb-3">Get in Touch</h1>
        <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(sendEmail)}>
          <div className="form-group mb-0 py-3">
            <textarea className="form-control custom--fields-mod text-the-primary" id="message" rows="3" placeholder="Message *" name="message" {...register("message", { required: true })}></textarea>
            {errors.message && <span className="invalid-feedback d-block">Please fill out this field.</span>}
          </div>        
          <div className="form-group row py-2 mb-0">
              <div className="col-md-6">
                <div>
                  <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <input className="mr-2" type="checkbox" id="yes_i_understand" name="yes_i_understand" {...register("yes_i_understand", { required: true })} />
                    <label className="font-size-12 mb-0" htmlFor="yes_i_understand">I understand and agree to the Privacy Policy and Terms and Conditions.</label>
                  </div>{errors.yes_i_understand && <span className="invalid-feedback d-block">You must agree before submitting.</span>}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6 text-center text-md-left py-2 py-md-0">
                <input className="buttons-width float-md-right btn btn-dark-moderate-orange rounded-0" type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" />
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );

}
export default NameForm;
```

I saw the react hook form samples, but I'm not sure if i missed something on passing the data to the form.

You can check it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-using-emailjs-2k6x5

Comment: Updated with links to https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-using-emailjs-2k6x5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Guillaume's answer fixes the problem the following solution would be the way to handle it only using `react-hook-form` and not using the `event` object at all. So just use the `emailjs.send` method and pass the form values provided by RHF to this method. To reset the form you could use the `reset` method of RHF.

```js
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  reset,
  formState: { errors }
} = useForm();
const sendEmail = (formData) => {
  emailjs
    .send("YOUR_SERVICE_ID", "YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID", formData, "YOUR_USER_ID")
    .then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
      }
    );
  reset();
};
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form using Emailjs (forked)]

Comment: This one looks good, however after successful submission, please try to click the button again wihout refreshing the page and fill the checkbox, you need to double click the checkbox to make the error validation works.

Comment: Yes, sorry - you're right. I forgot to provide the `defaultValues` for the form via the config options for `useForm`. You can read more about `reset` [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset). I updated the CodeSandbox, please test again.

Comment: Yeah i got it and its working, mine I just removed the message from the defaultValues. You can check mine here if it is right and ok. thanks!
`https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-using-emailjs-2k6x5`

Comment: It's looking good.   Although it would be better to provide `defaultValues` for all your form fields.

Comment: knoefel hope you can help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038402/react-hook-form-how-to-reset-the-form-content-after-submission

Answer (score 4):

The handleSubmit function calls your sendEmail with two parameters. The first one is the form data and the second one is the event.

This should solve your issue :

```
const sendEmail = (data, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .sendForm("YOUR_SERVICE_ID", "YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID", e.target, "YOUR_USER_ID")
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
    e.target.reset();
  };
```

Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-using-emailjs-forked-s2pey