# No data available using React Hook Form and EmailJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, react-forms

I'm trying to use this solution: [TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function on React Hook Form using EmailJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69010847/typeerror-e-preventdefault-is-not-a-function-on-react-hook-form-using-emailjs/70013118#70013118), but I'm getting another error. Even using the same code. Has anything changed lately with EmailJS?

> Error: The 3rd parameter is expected to be the HTML form element

[image]

Could someone help me, please? This is driving me crazy.

**EDIT: This solution is working for me.**

sendEmail function:

```
const sendEmail = (formData, e) => {
  // Send email
  emailjs.sendForm("YOUR_SERVICE_ID", "YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID", e.target, "YOUR_USER_ID")
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
    });
    reset();
};
```

and my form (using styled-components):

```
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(sendEmail)}>
                    <FormH1>Register your information</FormH1>
                    <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
                    <FormInput
                        {...register("name", {
                        required: true,
                        maxLength: 20,
                        pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i
                    })} type="text" name="name"/>
                        {errors?.name?.type === "required" && <FormError>This field is required</FormError>}
                        {errors?.name?.type === "maxLength" && <FormError>First name cannot exceed 20 characters</FormError>}
                        {errors?.name?.type === "pattern" && <FormError>Alphabetical characters only</FormError>}
                    <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                    <FormInput
                        {...register("email", {
                        required: true,
                        pattern: /\S+@\S+\.\S+/
                    })} type="email" name="email"/>
                        {errors?.email?.type === "required" && <FormError>This field is required</FormError>}
                        {errors?.email?.type === "pattern" && <FormError>Entered value does not match email format</FormError>}
                    <FormLabel>ORCID</FormLabel>
                    <FormInput {...register("orcid", { 
                        required: true,
                        minLength: 16, 
                        maxLength: 16,
                        pattern: /^[0-9\b]+$/
                    })} type="number" name="orcid"/>
                        {errors?.orcid?.type === "required" && <FormError>This field is required</FormError>}
                        {errors?.orcid?.type === "minLength" && <FormError>It must be a number of 16 digits</FormError> }
                        {errors?.orcid?.type === "maxLength" && <FormError>It must be a number of 16 digits</FormError> }
                        {errors?.orcid?.type === "pattern" && <FormError>Numerical characters only</FormError> }
                    <FormButton type="submit"/>
                </Form>
```

Comment: From where your <Form> is? Is it from bootstrap?

Comment: @VidarshanAdithya oh... yep. Well, I am using a custom tags in order to apply CSS on it. So `Form` must be `form`, right?

Comment: @VidarshanAdithya using the same code as the example and it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const emailData = {
      from_name: data.name,
      from_email: data.email,
      to_name: "Your app name",
      message: data.message,
    };

    emailjs
      .send(
        key1,
        key2,
        emailData,
        key3
      )
      .then(
        () => {
          reset();
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
  };
```

Comment: Could you describe a little what it does?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified the type of forms you are using, try this method using plain `html` forms.

The name tag you give to these input fields are extremely important as they are extracted as same as their name is and if your names in the `EmailJS` template does not match with the names, it will not work.

The submit method:

```
const sendEmail = (e) => {
  
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent default behaviour

  emailjs
  .sendForm(
    'your-emailjs-service-key',
    'your-emailjs-template-key',
    e.target,
    'your-emailjs-user-id'
  )
  .then(
    (result) => {
      console.log(result.text);
      });
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error)
      });
    }
  );

  e.target.reset(); //reset explicitly because default is prevented

};
```

The form:

```
<form onSubmit={sendEmail}>

   <input required type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
   <input required type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" />
   <input required type="number"  placeholder="ORCID" name="orcid" />

   <button>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: your example works. But notice that my example is quiet different. I'm using React Hook Form + EmailJS. I changed all my tags but that didn't work either.